# wrong alignment with miglayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

In jframe, I use miglayout for main jpanel position.

in the left panel, I have 2 jpanel, I use boxlayout.

ComponentPanel is the top left position and PropertyPanel is at the bottom left position.

```
    leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    leftPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

    add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    componentPanel = new ComponentPanel();
    propertyPanel = new PropertyPanel();
```

in the propertyPanel constructor, i do

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("debug"));
```

i get this

[image: mig layout]

why panel is setted to right?

if i add dynamically some space is added.

[image]

I tried to use fill to the miglayout constructor without success.

in green is the leftPanel
in red is the componentPanel

http://imagepaste.nullnetwork.net/img/1354548433miglayout3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Using BorderLayout instead of BoxLayout seem better...

```
leftPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
leftPanel.add(componentPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
leftPanel.add(propertyPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

BoxLayout problem?